# VB .net form gets hung up (can't click on form) after my loop ends

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I have a project that I am putting together. After I enter a loop to enter items into a listbox from input boxes (number of boxes determined from prior listbox) - it ends the loop at the correct time, however, I am then unable to click on the form at all. Nothing is sticking out clearly as to why this is happening. I have to stop debugging to close the form. Any ideas?

```
Private Sub btnEnterBib_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnEnterBib.Click
        ' The btnEnterBib click event accepts and x number of Bib numbers. 
        ' 1 for each time entry.
        ' Declare and initialize variables

        Dim strBibEntry As String = CStr(0)
        Dim strInputMessage As String = "Enter the BIB #"
        Dim strInputHeading As String = "BIB Entry"
        Dim strNegativeError As String = "Error - Enter a positive number for the Bib #"
        Dim strNonNumericError As String = "Error - Enter a positive number for the Bib #"
        Dim intNumberofEntries As Integer = 1
        Dim intBibNum As Integer = 0
        Dim intTotalEntries As Integer = 0
        Dim strCancelClicked As String = " "
        Dim intMaxNumberofEntries As Integer = (lstTimeEntry.Items.Count)



        Do Until intTotalEntries > intMaxNumberofEntries Or strBibEntry = strCancelClicked
            If intNumberofEntries <= intMaxNumberofEntries Then
                strBibEntry = InputBox(strInputMessage & intNumberofEntries, strInputHeading, " ")
            End If
            If IsNumeric(strBibEntry) Then
                intBibNum = Convert.ToInt32(strBibEntry)
                If intBibNum > 0 Then
                    lstBibs.Items.Add(strBibEntry)
                    intNumberofEntries += 1

                Else
                    strInputMessage = strNegativeError
                End If
            Else
                strInputMessage = strNonNumericError
            End If

        Loop

        btnSyncTimesBibs.Enabled = True
        btnEnterBib.Enabled = False

    End Sub
```

Comment: Can you verify that the line `btnSyncTimesBibs.Enabled = True` is hit?

Comment: I think so...but since I can't click on any part of the form (cannot even x out) - its hard to know for certain

Comment: You should confirm if it is hit or not. Try `Debug.WriteLine` in code or a breakpoint or something. That should help you to understand where to look for the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an infinite loop. You set `intTotalEntries` to 0, and you control the loop by checking if `intTotalEntries` is greater than `intMaxNumberOfEntries`, which I assume is never negative.

Within your loop, you never alter `intTotalEntries`.  Instead, you use `intNumberOfEntries`, also comparing it to `intMaxNumberOfEntries`.  You use this to decide if you should accept more entries, and you do increment `intNumberOfEntries`.  Once that variable exceeds the max, you no longer accept input.  This is why you believe the loop is ending. In fact it is now off to the races, because `intTotalEntries` is always zero, and can never be greater than the max.

As you have seen, an infinite loop will lock everything up solid until the program is forcibly terminated.

I suspect you didn’t mean to have two separate variables that seem to count the entries.  Also the first If statement isn’t needed.

Try this:

```
Do Until intNumberOfEntries > intMaxNumberOfEntries Or strBibEntry = strCancelClicked
    strBibEntry = InputBox(strInputMessage & intNumberOfEntries, strInputHeading, " ")
    'Remainder of your code here
Loop
```

Comment: OMG BLESS YOU.  I didn't even realize I had 2 variables intended to do the same thing, I was getting frustrated and looking at my old projects to try to figure it out, seems I wasn't paying enough attention. This is what I get when I stare at something too long.  Thank you! =)